# Can you add a shadow to the mouse pointer in css/html/jquery?

Tags: css, mouse, shadow

I couldn't find this question on here:

Is there a way to create a shadow for the mouse on a website?  Could someone point me in the direction to find out how to do this, if it's possibile?

thanks!

---

**update-1** 
Anyone know of anything like this for jquery then?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm I guess this could become difficult if you want to stick with the default cursor of each operating system. You can attach a custom image which contains a shadow with

```
element{
    cursor:url(custom.cur),url(custom.gif),auto;
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting approach! So rather than adding a shadow to the default cursor , I can replace it with a 'stock' cursor img and give that shadow. I'll give that a try.

Also, why did you write url(custom.gif) twice? could you explain that please? thanks!

Comment: Note also that you will need a .cur for old IEs.

Comment: sorry one time it should be *.cur - i am not completely sure why this is needed but I guess this ensures cross browser compatibility!

Answer (score 0):

Don't have anywhere to point you, but you could absolutely have a div that houses an image that's a blurred out grey version of the cursor (you'd probably have to detect what OS the user is using to determine exactly what image to serve, since cursors can vary) and then just bind the div to the mouse coordinates, but offset a bit.

Comment: Overly complex - you can set any cursor you want.

Comment: He's not asking how to set a cursor, he's asking how to set a shadow, therefor a second copy of the cursor underneath the original cursor.

Comment: I gave the reason about 5 seconds before you asked.

Comment: True, better solution. Same caveat as my solution, though: you may serve the user a cursor that isn't their default and then what do we have? Geocities and sparkles.

Comment: The problem with your solution is you have to have javascript events updating the HTML DOM and re-rendering the page every time the user moves the mouse. I agree custom cursors are *usually* dumb. There are valid uses for them though - HTML applications, HTML5 apps, games etc.

Comment: If you're styling the page anyway with colours and fonts that aren't the user's preference, why not style the cursor as well?